# Is there a way to have a search value and hash in url?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made an URL ROUTER using hash (e.g. #User.Account)
And i'm trying to add a search value to it (e.g. #/User.Account?id=729)
How do i do that?

My router works by doing

```
    if(window.location.hash == "#User.Account") {
      // show account page code
    }
```

Comment: Did you try URL api ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API. Here you have more info about params https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append

Answer (score 0):

```
history.pushState(null,null,'#User.Account?id=729');
```